# libvirt and watchdog notification: missing notifications on the host

Tags: libvirt, watchdog

I am trying to get my guest VM's watchdog fired notifications on host using the following python script.

https://github.com/wiedi/libvirt/blob/master/examples/domain-events/events-python/event-test.py

I tried the following in my Ubuntu guest VM in order to get notifications on the host:

-- configured the watchdog to ping an unreachable host and just syslog if there is no response; used "watchdog -q" command for this.

-- configured the watchdog to ping an unreachable host and reboot if there is no response;  used "watchdog -b" command for this.

In both cases, the watchdog fires because the WD is trying to ping a random IP address. I see the syslog that the watchdog fired because there is no response from the IP address.

But on the host, there is no notification whatsoever. In the second case above (watchdog -b), the guest reboots and the script gets a "myDomainEventRebootCallback" notification while i was expecting "myDomainEventWatchdogCallback".

Any idea how to get watchdog fired notifications on the host?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned whether you actually added a virtual watchdog device in the guest configuration ? The libvirt watchdog event notifications only occur if you have added a virtual watchdog device.

If you haven't, then the guest watchdog device will just be using a NMI to emulate a watchdog and this merely triggers a normal guest OS reboot.

So you need to make sure you have a `i6300esb` device added as shown in this example:

https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsWatchdog

Comment: The guest's XML has a virtual watchdog XML configuration just like you mentioned. I've even tried various actions; reset/poweroff etc. When the WD in the guest fires, the host somehow doesn't any notification. The actions are working as expected though; i mean if the action is reset, the guest resets. If the action is none, all i see is debug logs in /var/log/syslog of the guest.